# «Que philosopher, c'est apprendre à mourir»

Tags: grammaire, infinitif, moyen-français

What's the grammatical purpose of **que** in this construction (due to Cicéron)? I would have expected it to read, «Philosopher, c'est apprendre à mourir».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est le titre *[d'un essai de Montaigne](http://www.bribes.org/trismegiste/es1ch19.htm)*.

La traduction *[en français contemporain](http://www.heracleitos.eu/Textes/Montaigne/Essais_I_19,_trad._G._De_Pernon.pdf)* supprime le *que*.

- Chapitre XVIII [où il est dit] - « *Qu*'il ne faut juger de notre heur qu’après la mort »
- Chapitre XIX - [où il est dit] - « *Que* philosopher, c'est apprendre à mourir »
- Chapitre XX -- [où l'on parle] « *De* la force de l'imagination »

*Que* sert plutôt à introduire une discussion philosophique.
*De* le développement d'une idée plus personnelle.

On peut retrouver cette façon de donner un titre au texte que l'on se propose de développer dans des domaines contemporains :

- [Qu'*il en soit ainsi*](http://www.paroles.net/poetic-lover/paroles-qu-il-en-soit-ainsi)
- [De *l'art de...*](http://voyagesetvagabondages.com/2014/03/pates-bologne/)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the contemporary French translation!